# Create a Counter that resets with every change in name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

This site has been a great resource for me over the years but I finally ran into an issue i couldn't find a solution for already posted.

I have a list of names, dates and values. I need to turn the dates into the numbers and for them to start over for each well where value is greater than 0.

My thought was to create a loop but I'm short on skills to make it happen.

I found a post to create the counter but not how to loop it:

```
SELECT Name, row_number() over (order by (select NULL))
FROM [$ST_MASTER]
```

The Yellow Column Is What I Want to Create

[image]

Comment: please tag the dbms being used. Also, tell us if this reset has to occur for each name.

Comment: sql-server 

The reset has to occur at each name change.

Comment: if there are values like 0,120,0,90,0,10..how should the column values look like for a given name? should they be 0,1,0,2,0,3 or 0,1,0,1,0,1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're in the right direction.   Your over by need to change in two ways:
1)  You need to restart the row number with each name.
2)  You need to restart the row number when the value becomes zero.
After this, we just need to discard the row numbers for zero quantity rows.  You'll see I did this by using the ZeroOnePartSort value.
One flow in this logic:  This assumes (per your data sample) that once quantities go positive for a name, they don't go to zero again.

```
WITH ValSort  AS (
SELECT Name, CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ZeroOnePart,
     DateStamp, Value FROM dbo.STMaster
  )
SELECT vs.Name, vs.DateStamp, vs.Value, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vs.Name, vs.ZeroOnePart
              ORDER BY vs.DateStamp) * vs.ZeroOnePart 
FROM ValSort vs
```

Comment: This worked like a champ. The over and partition by functions are new to me. Thank you guys.